# How can I auto-create a partition in a declarative partitioned table in Postgres when a newly created row has no matching partition?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, partitioning, functions

My goal here is to make a partitioned table that's simplified below

| Group | Info |
| --- | --- |
| A | blah1 |
| B | blah2 |

but instead of having that as one table, I want to partition my table per group so that there's a table_1 for group 1, table_2 for group 2, etc. because my queries are all bound by group.

What I tried so far is creating a partitioned table like so

```
CREATE TABLE main_table (
  group TEXT
  blah JSONB
) PARTITION BY LIST(group);
```

I created my first manual partition like so

```
CREATE TABLE table_a PARTITION OF main_table FOR VALUES IN ('A');
```

I then created a function like so in the hope that I could set up a trigger on each row

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_node_partition() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $auto_add_node_partition$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nodes_org_%I PARTITION OF nodes_main FOR VALUES IN ($1)', NEW.org_id) USING NEW.org_id;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$auto_add_node_partition$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But the attempt to add a trigger on the `main_table`  like so

```
CREATE TRIGGER auto_add_node_partition BEFORE INSERT ON nodes_main FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE add_node_partition();
```

failed because of the following error

```
ERROR:  "nodes_main" is a partitioned table
DETAIL:  Partitioned tables cannot have ROW triggers.
```

and I can't use a statement trigger because the only way to access the passed in rows is with transition tables that are only accessible after the operation (which will fail since there's no partition).

Does anyone know how to build this partitioned table system? Thank you so much!

Comment: Postgres 13 allows row level triggers, but this still wouldn't work as the target partition must be known before the trigger is executed. You simply can't have "dynamic" partitions in Postgres

Comment: Why do you try to re-invent the wheel? This extension will do that for you https://pgxn.org/dist/pg_partman/